# Fixing a slippery Sidewalk

Tags: concrete, removal

Last year I had  our crumbling front path replaced. I live in the North Eastern  U.S. and the weather can be slippery. The path was sealed ( unknown type) and the path had some grit  but not enough. The path becomes dangerously slippery under a layer of snow.

I wish to address the problem by using a suitable paint (Behr Granite Lock). The instructions call for stripping of the sealant and using muriatic acid.
Is that necessary to use the muriatic acid as I believe it will remove the stamped pattern?

Comment: AIUI, the muriatic acid will eat away the coating and leave a light surface texture for the new coating to mechanically adhere to. However, it shouldn't etch it so heavily that it would remove a stamped pattern unless the stamping is _very_ shallow. Do you have any references indicating that it would do so? Maybe include a picture of your path so that those with more experience could help make a judgement.

Comment: I've used Granite Lock for pool areas and it works great in creating a non slip surface in a wet area but I'm not convinced it will do well under snow.    You  might want to stick with the old fashioned shovel and salt method. Just my humble opinion.

Comment: Also, "is it necessary to use muriatic acid" - is answerable by what the directions on the can of new stuff says. If that's what it calls for, that's what it calls for. I'm sure you can apply it without stripping the old sealer off (the new paint won't jump away or refuse to go down), but don't expect it to last long if the surface isn't properly prepared. (Just like any paint job.)

Answer (score 1):

Do not remove any coatings on top of your concrete, especially in a snowy climate.

What you are proposing will not help your situation at all.   The snow/ice will bind to the paint layer the same as it does now and it will be just as slippery.   However by taking away some of the protection of the concrete, it will fail faster.

You have two options:

1. Shovel the snow and use a forms of chemicals/salts to clear the path.   If you have to use chemicals/salts your walkway will not last as long and you may damage nearby grass/plants.
2. Put a topping on the walkway.   I have seen sand, mulch, and all kinds of things sprinkled.   These help a ton.   The most effective thing I have seen is little twigs thrown across the walkway.

These are the only two options that the whole world has.   Your area and your walkway are not unique.   The application that you are proposing has nothing to do with your problem and will cost you time, money, and make your walkway deteriorate faster.

Comment: Agreed. Nothing will do well under snow pack and ice.